# How to redirect traffic nginx in dynamic mode

Tags: nginx, redirect, dynamic, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

In my nginx server , I want to do this:

```
mydomain.com/api/xxxx

redirect to mynewdomain.com/api/testing/xxxx
```

I try to do by different ways but no ones works for me, always return a 502 error;

#### First way

> ```
>   server {
>   listen 80;
>   server_name mydomain.com;
>   # Nginx conf
>   location /api/ {
>     return 301 https://mynewdomain.com/api/testing/$uri;
>   }
> }
> ```

#### Second way

> ```
> server {
>   listen 80;
>   server_name mydomain.com;
>   # Nginx conf
>   location /api/(.*) {
>    proxy_pass https://mynewdomain.com/api/testing/$args_v;
>   }
> }
> ```

And I tryed to only redirect to specific direction and this works, but i don't want to hardcode all petitions to redirect,

#### Static redirect

> ```
>    server {
>       listen 80;
>       server_name mydomain.com;
>       # Nginx conf
>       location /api/ {
>         proxy_pass https://mynewdomain.com/api/testing/redirect1;
>       }
> ```

Any help for make this dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/api/(.*) {
  return 301 https://mynewdomain.com/api/testing/$1;
}
```

Try this, because $uri also includes /api.

Comment: @Pol did my solution work for you? If so, could you mark it as a solution please? thanks.